# How to pass data manually to datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am trying datatables. I successfully tried on ajax call. But now I am looking for loading my data grid, using datatables of course, on page load.

I need to pass arguments to my processing page via querystring. Page does the operation and then a template file shows the datagrid. This all was being done in smarty using manual foreach and other loops. Now I want to convert it all to datatables.

But how that initial data is going be passed to datatables? Therefore I need to pass initial data to datatables, but how? I referred to datatables api and other references but did not any such thing. Please help

I wish to do something like this

```
<?php
    //get params from $_GET
    $dbRet = someDbOps($someGetParams); //db processing
    include_once('grid.tpl');
?>
```

on grid.tpl

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jq.js"></script>
        <script src="datatables.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var data = '<?php echo $dbRet?>'; //now i got data here
            $('#one-column-emphasis').dataTable({
                    "bProcessing" : true,
                    "bServerSide" : true,
                    "sAjaxSource" : "changeLog.php",
                    "bPaginate"   : true,
                    "aoColumns"   : [ "Topic", "Details", "Date" ],
                    "aaSorting"   : [[1,"desc"]]
            }); // how to pass $dbRet to this handler????
        </script>
         <table id="one-column-emphasis">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using smarty functions to access the database (as someDbOps($someGetParams); sugests, or php functions, IE, mysql_query();

Comment: that is just a sample code snippet kind of thing I wrote there. That is a php function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [aaData](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) and pass an array of value, or you could simply draw the first page of the table and then handle retrieving the other rows through ajax

Comment: I copy pasted this exact same thing and got this error `g[h - d] is undefined`

Comment: ok, found the error. Stupid mistake. Ok, trying out your suggestion. That php output variable is in json format, in some way gotta create a  js array of it and then feed it to aaData. I think that will work.

Comment: Use mDataProp rather than making a separate array: http://datatables.net/blog/Extended_data_source_options_with_DataTables

Comment: @Shades88 in that case as allan suggested is much better to use mDataProp

Comment: I tried this...
`var data = '[{ "cell1": "row 1, cell 1","cell2": "row 1, cell 2"},{ "cell1": "row 2, cell 1","cell2": "row 2, cell 2"}]';
 $('#xample').dataTable({
   "aaData"   : data,
   "bPaginate"   : true,
   "aoColumns": [ { "mDataProp": "cell1" },{ "mDataProp": "cell2" }   ]
 });`

Gave me error: `DataTables warning (table id = 'xample'): Requested unknown parameter 'cell1' from the data source for row 0`

Comment: ok, now I got first draw of table working. Now how can I call ajax using same handler? I am using my own custom ajax wrapper. I check result.error on success if error is not 0 then I pass result.data to datatables handler. But that is first draw. For that I removed bProcessing, bServerside and sAjaxSource properties. Now after my initial data has been loaded how can I initiate ajax calls for pagination, sorting and all?

Comment: @Shades88 if you remove those options datatables will work assuming all the data is present on the client so it would be difficult to do, i'd suggest you open another question and post the relevant code.

Comment: Hey got it. I used `fnServerParams` to tell DataTables exactly what data to send to server and `fnServerData` which acts like custom ajax success wrapper. That lets me handle server response myself and take decisions, thereby, also letting me handle sorting, pagination etc.
Thanks everyone for your valuable suggestions and DataTables is awesome :D